# Webpack build fails for IE (11)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Trying to setup webpack to build my `.js` and `.vue` files.

Seems to no transpile `_name() {}` style function to regular JavaScript.

Thought it should do that out of the box, straight into commons js unless otherwise specified.

No idea why, it's crashing only in IE with some generic JS syntax error about semi colon out of place.

I guess some little flag, setting, something, somewhere.

Looking for some suggestions here.

**ex vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            _name() {
                return 'blah';
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**package.json**

```
"@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.42",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.0.0-beta.42",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0-beta.42",
"babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.2",

"vue-loader": "9.5.1",

"vue-style-loader": "1.0.0",
"sass-loader": "3.2.3",
"node-sass": "^4.1.1",
"css-loader": "0.25.0",
"style-loader": "0.13.1",
"vue-html-loader": "1.2.3",
"file-loader": "^0.8.4",

"webpack": "3.4.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "1.16.1",
"webpack-stream": "3.2.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
"replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.2",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.7"
```

**config**

```
entry: [__dirname + '/../src/bootstrap.js'],

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/../public',
    filename: 'app.min.js',
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash:4].js",
    publicPath: '/',
},

plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
        (function () {
            var copy = [{
                to: '',
                from: __dirname + '/../src/core/assets'
            }, {
                to: '',
                from: __dirname + '/../src/app/assets'
            }];

            if (data.copy) {
                copy.concat(data.copy);
            }

            return copy;
        })()
    ),

    new ReplacePlugin({
        skip: false,
        entry: 'src/index.html',
        output: '/public/index.html',
        hash: '[hash]',
        data: {
            scripts: data.scripts
        }
    })
],

module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',

        options: {
            loaders: {
                js: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                },
                sass: 'sass-loader'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

**build looks like this**

```
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });

/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ({
  props: ['name', 'timeout', 'max'],
  computed: {
    _name() {
      return this.name || 'global';
    },

    ...
```

**EDIT:**

In the end it was just a matter of adding a few specific transform plugins in the `.babelrc` file at the root. Probably better way to do this via config. Took a while to match the transforms to each error, but the following set worked for me.

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties"
    ]
}
```

Note: each plugin needs to be installed as a dependency also.

Comment: Just on a side note: Why don't you use the new (official) `vue-cli` 3 build, where the whole build configuration is abstracted into versioned npm modules?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 still seems like it's gonna be quite a bit of tinkering, and it's an existing project, so I just need a build that works.

Comment: Please, add your babel configuration to the question, if there is any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a custom webpack configuration and it is not clear there is any additional configuration to babel, try to add [@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-shorthand-properties.html) plugin to `babel-loader` options for `.vue` files.

```
loaders: {
  js: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties']
    }
  },
  sass: 'sass-loader'
}
```

Comment: This led me down the right road, check edit for full answer if anyone comes here.

Answer (score 3):

**from the output it is confirmed that shorthand property is not getting transpiled**

you are using the shorthand property of ES6 which is not supported on iE you need to configure the babel config so that it transpiled this into older version ( for more info about browser support visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions))

to make your babel config compatible for ie use something like this in `babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
      },
        "useBuiltIns": true
    }],

  ]
}
```

if that dosen't work try changing you `devtool` config in webpack (for example `eval` to something else ) and check [this thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7935) of github